# Which of the following Minkowski sums are open/closed?

Tags: general-topology

Consider the sets
\begin{align*}
W \ \ &= \ \ \{(x,y) \ \ \in R^2 \ \ | \ \ x >0,y>0\} \\
X \ \ &= \ \ \{(x,y) \ \ \in R^2 \ \ | \ \ x \in R,y = 0\} \\
Y \ \ &= \ \ \{(x,y) \ \ \in R^2 \ \ | \ \ xy \ \ = \ \ 1\} \\
Z\ \ &= \ \ \{(x,y) \ \ \in R^2 \ \ | \ \ |x|  \leq 1, |y| \leq 1\}
\end{align*}

Which of the followings are true

1. The set $W + X$ is open
2. The set $X + Y$ is closed
3. The set $Y + Z$ is closed

I think

1. $W + X = \{(x,y) \ \ \in R^2 \ \ | \ \ x \in \mathbb R,y>0\}$ which is open
2. $X + Y = \{(x,y) \ \ \in R^2 \ \ | \ \ x \in \mathbb R,y\neq0\}$ which is open
3. $Y + Z$ is closed , because $Y$ and $Z$ are closed

I would be thankful who give me your valuable time for checking my solution.

Comment: Your definition for $A+B$ needs to be clarified. What are you doing with the elements $a \in A$ and $b\in B$? Are you doing position-wise addition?

Comment: @John Habert : yes this is a position-wise(point-wise addition)

Answer (score 1):

Sum of two closed sets need not be closed. So the reason you gave for (3) is wrong!

Comment: @user120386 Counterexamples can be found in introductory functional analysis textbooks. 
However in your special example the set $Z$ is compact, and generally, if the set $A$ is closed, the set $B$ is compact, then $A+B$ is closed.

Comment: what about (1) and (2)

Comment: (1) is correct as if U is open in any normed linear space X, then U+A is open for any set A in X.